# Confused about negating a recursion condition, example code included

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion

Okay, so I'm trying to write a deepEquals function that compares objects in javascript and tells you if they are equal or not. That is, if the objects have the same properties, and if those same properties have the same values. Order of properties doesn't matter. I am confused about the recursion part of the code, and why it works. I've watched a video where she writes almost the same code as I am but I don't understand how she gets hers to work. Anyway, here's her code which works:

```
let deepEquals = (a,b) => {
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a && b && typeof a === 'object' && typeof b === 'object' && Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length) {
        for (let key in a) {
            if (key in b) {
                if (!deepEquals(a[key], b[key])) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return false;
            } 
            }
             return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

And here's mine which doesn't work:

```
let deepEquals = (a,b) => {

    if ( a === b ) {
        return true;
    } else if ( a && b && typeof a === 'object' && typeof b === 'object' && Object.keys(a).length === Object.keys(b).length ) {
        for ( let key in a ) {
            if ( key in b ) {
                deepEquals(a[key], b[key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

```
let person = {
    lastName: "Bone",
    firstName: "Jordan",
    age: 34,
    position: "Information Technology",
    nest: {
        value: 13,
        lamp: "no",
        etc: false,
        testNull: null
    }
}

let person1 = {
    firstName: "Jordan",
    lastName: "Bone",
    age: 34,
    position: "Information Technology",
    nest: {
        value: 13,
        lamp: "no",
        etc: false,
        testNull: null
    }
}

console.log(deepEquals(person, person1));
C:\Node\Jordan\JSON>node deepEqualsYouTube.js
false
```

My questions are:

a. Obviously, why isn't mine working?
b. What does the if (!deepEquals(a[key], b[key]) statement saying? I've never seen recursion used like that. How does this make the code work?
c. Why does she put a "return true;" statement after the for {} block? Why is it placed there and when does the code fall to that?

If anyone could enlighten me to what I'm doing here that would be great. Thank you very much.

Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** You are discarding the result of `deepEquals` if the key exists in both objects.

Change

```
if ( key in b ) {
    deepEquals(a[key], b[key]);
}
```

To

```
if (!( key in b ) || !deepEquals(a[key], b[key])){
   return false;
}
```

**b)** `(!deepEquals(a[key], b[key])` is checking that the result of calling `deepEquals` on the values of the objects `a` and `b` at the key `key` is false, i.e. the values are not deeply equal.

**c)** There is a `return true` after the loop because the loop checks for any of the values not being deeply equal. Execution will only reach that point if all of the values are equal, i.e. `deepEquals(a[key], b[key])` did not return false for any `key` and both objects have the same keys. At this point, the two objects have been proven to be deeply equal.

Comment: Can you possibly explain to me more in-depth? What do you mean I am discarding the results? What does negating the function do (!deepEquals) -- does that mean if it returns true, return false? Or it if returns false, return true?

Comment: Ah okay, I think I'm understanding. I still have one more question though, and I really appreciate your insight.  At the start of the function, at if ( a === b ) {return true}; -- wouldn't this exit the function as soon as it gets a recursive call where a === b and not finish going through the rest of the keys? How does it not exit there?

Comment: @Jordan If `a` and `b` are strictly equal, then they are certainly equal, in which case there is no need to iterate over the keys.

Comment: Thank you for all your help hev1, but I am still a bit confused. At the start of the function, it says if ( a === b ) {return true}; So, when the for..in loop recurses and calls the function again with a[key] and b[key], those two object values are going to return true when compared with ===. So at that point, wouldn't the function stop executing and not iterate through the rest of the object at the first matching pair ( a === b ) = true it encounters? Or am I being confused with the call stack? as in, even though the recursed function exits, the for loop persists? Thanks again. -Jordan

Comment: @Jordan About what?

Comment: @Jordan `===` is used for strict equality comparison. Two objects are only strictly equal if they are the same object reference, or they have the same value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: @Jordan No, the function would not stop recursing. On each iteration of the loop, it checks `if (!deepEquals(a[key], b[key]))`, so if the values at the keys are not deeply equal, it returns false. Otherwise, it will continue to check the other keys. In other words, returning true for a specific value does not mean it will return true for the entire object.

Comment: @Jordan Do you understand now?

Comment: I think I understand now. The for loop persists and even though when (a === b) is true, it continues with the loop and doesn't exit the current function. This seems like such a basic thing to get hung up on but I've never really seen recursion used like this. Thanks again hev1

Comment: @Jordan No problem.